# Win32com.client com_error

Tags: python, error-handling

Today suddenly I am getting following error.

```
import win32com.client
xl=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel Application")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    xl=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel Application")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 95, in Dispatch
    dispatch, userName = dynamic._GetGoodDispatchAndUserName(dispatch,userName,clsctx)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 108, in     _GetGoodDispatchAndUserName
    return (_GetGoodDispatch(IDispatch, clsctx), userName)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 85, in  _GetGoodDispatch
    IDispatch = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(IDispatch, None, clsctx, pythoncom.IID_IDispatch)
com_error: (-2147221005, 'Invalid class string', None, None)
```

What is wrong?

Comment: sounds like the clsid in your registry is screwed up, If you have a good registry cleaner, run it and see if that fixes your issue

Comment: @johnathon:I tried to clean my registry with ccleaner and auslogics cleaner but error remains, any other possibilities?

Answer (score 0):

It might be a little bit late for an anwser, but you are missing the dot between Excel and Application. "Excel.Application").